# Facebook app links don't open app when post is clicked in 2017

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I've added app links headers for my web site with metadata for my iOS app, but they don't open app when post is clicked. Is app links works as described in documentation in 2017? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content)

Comment: are you added the url schema in developer .facebook and your app

Comment: yes. But anyway documentation says that if I don't have my App installed, App link will redirect me to the App Store

Comment: ya you need to add your appstore link in deep link page

Answer (score 2):

## This is expected behavior

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to directly launch a third-party app from within the iOS Facebook app. This is a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1640178609532119/) that Facebook has essentially written off as `wontfix`. This is still possible in the Android Facebook app, but it's unfortunate they haven't been more transparent about the change to the iOS version because there is quite a bit of confusion about it.

Instagram is a special case because it is a Facebook-owned app and gets different treatment.

### But you can work around it

Services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I am on the team) get around this by implementing a judicious combination of App Links, URI schemes, and iOS Universal Links. Essentially what you need to do is open a page in the webview and then have a button or other user-driven CTA event that launches the app from there. It's an extra step for the user, but currently the best workaround. If you just want to be able to post a link that goes into your app when it is installed and otherwise goes to a webpage (or the App/Play Store), then Branch links are definitely your simplest solution.

*Branch link routing logic*

[image: Branch link routing logic]